# Multiple step onClick Javascript form

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

Could anyone please give me an example of how to create a multple step form where each stage is submitted by onClick then using hidden inputs or variables to store the values from previous pages?

For example:

Step 1...

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="yes" onclick="this.form.submit()" />

<input type="radio" name="group1" value="no" onclick="this.form.submit()" />
```

Step 2...

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="100" onclick="this.form.submit()" />

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="200" onclick="this.form.submit()" />

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="300" onclick="this.form.submit()" />


<!-- previous input -->
<input type="hidden" name="group1" value="200" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it better to hide the parts that don't belong to the step and submit the entire form only once at the last step?

Comment: @Th0rndike. should have been an answer...

Comment: I don't really mind storing all details until submission for example in a session variable but the main thing I am trying to acheive is a multiple stage form without a 'next' button: where the next question is generated automatically when a selection is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as i said in the comment, create only one form: (code is highly unformatted and serves only for comprehension purposes)

```
<form>
     <input class='step1input'/>
     <input class='step1input'/>
      <input class='step2input'/>
     <input class='step2input'/>
     ...
 </form>
```

at the first step hide the inputs that dont belong there (step2input classes)

at second step, hide the other inputs (step1input classes)

etc...

at the end of the last step you submit the ENTIRE form

EDIT: what you're doing is fine, only, instead of submitting the form, you just hide the elements. use a jquery or javascript function like this:

```
 function goToNextStep(currentStep){
    if (currentStep==1) {
       $('input[name='group1']').hide();
       $('input[name='group2']').show();
    }else if (currentStep==2){
         ...
    }
    ...
    else if (currentStep==lastStep){
        document.form.submit();
    }
 }
```

Step 1...

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="yes" onclick="goToNextStep(1)" />

<input type="radio" name="group1" value="no" onclick="goToNextStep(1)" />
```

Step 2...

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="100" onclick="goToNextStep(2)" />

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="200" onclick="goToNextStep(2)" />

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="300" onclick="goToNextStep(2)" />
```

Comment: So would the form elements be hidden using css? Sorry for being thick but could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like this plugin:

http://www.michaelpeacock.co.uk/blog/entry/multistep-form-navigation-jquery-plugin

this one is quite simple too:

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx

or here is a more detailed plugin:

http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer in my question, I was trying to get the form to work without 'next' buttons to go to the next stage. so when the user clicks a selection they are automatically taken to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you miss a JS function that shows only a respective form part and hides the remaining parts.

Here an example with three steps. Check the [JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/joao_pimentel/q0afo8ph/).

In HTML just insert

```
<body onload="shows_form_part(1)">
  <form>
    <div id="form_part1">
      <!--form elements 1-->
      <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&raquo;</button>
    </div>
    <div id="form_part2">
      <!--form elements 2-->
      <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(1)">&laquo;</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(3)">&raquo;</button>
    </div>
    <div id="form_part3">
      <!--form elements 3-->
      <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&laquo;</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="submit_form()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

in Javascript define this function, that shows only the respective form part and hides the remaining parts.

```
function shows_form_part(n){
    var i = 1, p = document.getElementById("form_part"+1);
    while (p !== null){
        if (i === n){
            p.style.display = "";
        }
        else{
            p.style.display = "none";
        }
        i++;
        p = document.getElementById("form_part"+i);
    }
}
```

Then you just need to define the `submit_form()` function.

The HTML characters `&laquo;` and `&raquo;` just print respectively « and » which might be interesting for the previous and next button characters.